# Send Android Push Notifications to Multiple Devices using PHP, PDO, MYSQL

Tags: php, android, mysql, pdo

I have seen many tutorials for sending push notifications to Android devices using php and mysql but i would like to use PDO to implement this, i have been trying to figure out the problem, i am getting "invalid registration" but it is working if i directly assign gcm registration id to variable but not if i am getting gcm registration id from database. I think the problem is with the structure of array  am getting from PDO

Here is the error i am getting

```
{"multicast_id":5263664448936997879,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
```

When i echo the array i am sending

```
    Array ( [registration_ids] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [gcm_id] => APA91bGZs7DIb2lVvtlx-Ltgz2_wbRcMIvy-MfYPxoXt6SyDQlUjEnxgNTEw2vS6U5fe9u62i1LZo_gfhipUqT-FCgDj0U7JAwWwOvVmEhx9xIcs0k6mBsg7AgY6pxCVuaXYhqde0mZd ) ) ) [data] => Array ( [update] => thbtrhrt ) )
```

and my code is

```
function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {

    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
        'data' => $message,
    );
    print_r($fields);
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=AShthdfDeac36l6c6G1huGogerJDUvtvOPQ6hA',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}

function getGCMIds($univid) 
{
    global $dbConnect;

    $query = $dbConnect->prepare("SELECT gcmid FROM android_gcm_table WHERE univid = ?");
    $query->bindValue(1, $univid);
    $query->execute();

    try
    {
        return $results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } 
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

$gcmIds = getGCMIds($_POST['univ']); // if i directly paste the gcm reg id here and put $gcmIds in array then its working.
$notification  = $_POST['message'];
$notification = array("update" => $notification);


echo $resultLast = send_notification($gcmIds, $notification);
```

It would be great if someone help me, Thank You

Comment: just some tips: are you sure the registrationId stored in database is the full id? i mean what is the length of that field in the DB? is it enugh? try to use some `trim()` on that value too, as it may contain a space?

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN) Worked for me

```
function getGCMIds($univid) 
{
global $dbConnect;

$query = $dbConnect->prepare("SELECT gcmid FROM android_gcm_table WHERE univid = ?");
$query->bindValue(1, $univid);
$query->execute();

try
{
    return $results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
} 
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    die($e->getMessage());
}
}
```